# Swift - animateWithDuration completion bad access

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

```
   let downFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: ScreenSize.height, width: ScreenSize.width, height: ScreenSize.height-Constants.navBarHeight)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
      self.frame = self.downFrame
    },
    completion: nil)
```

[Animation move view out of screen. Then crash in comletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAgsK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code Work Very Well

What Is Value Of Self.downFrame?